# How to get Grails create-app working - New app homepage is getting 404

Tags: grails

- Hyper-V Ubuntu 20.04LTS
- Grails 5.1.9
- JDK 11.0.15
- Groovy 4.0.3
- SDKMAN

I am getting this after I run grails run-app.  It never gets to 100% (I am assuming it should).  I can hit the main url or localhost:8080, but get 404 (localhost:8080/myapp) using the appname I created with 'grails create-app myapp' or 'grails create-app myapp --profile=web'.  I am 1 day into grails.  I did check the controller code, and there is code for '/', 'index'.

[grails run-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ptG.png) image

Comment: I just tried.  I am using Windows.  It also says 85% and then a timer.  I can open a browser to just **localhost:8080** and I can see the page.  Will removing **/myapp** from the URL work?

Comment: "Will removing /myapp from the URL work?" - That won't have any impact on getting to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

> It never gets to 100% (I am assuming it should)

That is a reasonable expectation, but not the way it works.  It never gets to 100% because technically it isn't done until the process terminates.  As long as the app is running, the task is still in progress.

By default your context root will be localhost:8080/, not localhost:8080/myapp.